# React - Check if any nested objects contain a specific value

Tags: javascript

I apologize if this has been answered already - I have spent some time looking for the answer and haven't found it yet:

I have an array of items with many nested objects in it. This is a super simplified example:

```
  const array = [
    {
      name: "item1",
      categories: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "soft",
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "medium",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "item2",
      categories: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "medium",
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "hard",
        }
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a filter to return, for example, only the items that contain a category with the name "soft".

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: The array you posted there isn't valid. Are those outer brackets supposed to be curly braces?

Comment: I don't understand, is the `array` an object or an array? The solution depends on it

Comment: What are you using an object for storing item1, item2, etc? It would be better to have it as an array

Comment: it's updated. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, please make an attempt yourself first, before asking others to write the solution for you. You can start by looping over the properties of objects and the entries of arrays, and comparing the contents.

Comment: `name: soft` --- what is `soft`? Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const array = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'soft'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'medium'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'medium'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'hard'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const soft = array.filter(({ categories }) =>
  categories.some(({ name }) => name === 'soft')
);
```

The above will return only the items where it has a category with the name soft.